# MVC ajax casecade dropdown not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

I am created casecade dropdown but it always shows (500 (Internal Server Error)).I dont know what is the problem.

Here is my code

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult test()
{
   string val1 = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
   string[] result = { val1 };
   return Json(val1);
}
```

View ajax code

```
$(".target").change(function () {
            var region = $('.target').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("test")',
                data: { county: region },
                success: function (msg) {
                    var len = msg.length;

               for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

                   $("#country").val(msg[i]);
                   $('.country').append(
  $('<option></option>').val(msg[i]).html(msg[i])); 
               }

                }
            });


        });
```

Please help me any one know how to solve this problem

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: exactly when are you getting this error..?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a json object to the controller action yet, the controller action does not expect anything. You need to stringify the json object you are sending in the `data` option of your `ajax` request and change your controller action to...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult test(string country)
```

Comment: thank you answer my question.But the value came to controller.Sorry for i didnt put in this post.But it always shows 500 internal server error

Comment: You still need to stringify the json object you are sending in the ajax request. And please update your question to include relevant information